# How to include packages in PySpark when using notebooks on EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I'm currently trying to analyze some data using a notebook using EMR. The problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out how to when I'm using the PySpark kernel how to include specific artifacts. Specifically, I'm trying to include org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 which I would normally do in the command line when starting the PySpark environment by simply using the --packages argument. Do I have to include a Bootstrap action maybe? I'm not entirely certain what I would even put there. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I asked on reddit and someone from the EMR team answered:

You can use a `%%configure` block as the first cell in your notebook to specify additional packages. In your case, this would look like this:

```
%%configure
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0" }}
```

Here's a screenshot of an [example notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhHt8.jpg) that loads spark-avro.

(Disclaimer: AWS employee on the EMR team )

Comment: Hi Victor! Thanks for your answer, it works great with generic libraries. However, I am having some issues using this with for example a library called: Clustering4ever [link]https://github.com/Clustering4Ever/Clustering4Ever
Does your answer work with this type of libraries as well?? Sorry if the question is dumb but I am new to this and hitting my head against the wall!